# AWS IAM Policy to Enforce Multiple Tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, scp, policy, tagging

Is it possible to write this more succinctly I have tried a number of ways but all seem to fail. I have Tried adding all 3 conditions to one deny with ForAllValues or ForAnyValues but although the statements create the rules are not enforced entirely unless it is written like this.

```
{"Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Statement1",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Name": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Statement2",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Dept": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Statement3",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Owner": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Still interested if anyone has figured out how to accomplish this in a single statement

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into same scenario where i needed to enforce multiple tags on a single resource type and tried the below methods all of which failed.

ForAllValue is not suitable as it will allow resource creation if no tag keys are passed. Thus failing the scp purpose
ForAnyValue will not work as it will work like an OR operator between tag keys
aws:TagKeys don’t work as it also works as OR operator.

We can’t use same condition key like StringNotEquals multiple times in one condition operator.

So i also followed the same approach as suggested by you.
If anyone has a suggestion please suggest or i think it’s a feature miss at aws side

Comment: You also cannot use this:

```
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/costcenter": "true"
          "aws:RequestTag/tagkey2": "true"
          "aws:RequestTag/tagkey3": "true"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but putting this here because comments won't style...

You also cannot use this:

```
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/costcenter": "true"
          "aws:RequestTag/tagkey2": "true"
          "aws:RequestTag/tagkey3": "true"
        }
```

This turns the Null into an OR so as soon as one tag exists it will be not DENY